# How do you use a Typescript Function Interface with a Generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's consider we have the following function interface:

```
interface SomeFunction<T> {(arg: T) :T}
```

We can use the interface like so:

```
const myFun: SomeFunction<string> = arg => arg;
```

But the issue with that is we specify the generic type `T` as `string`. How can we leave `T` generic?

The only way I see how is basically not using `SomeFunction` in the functions signature. Like so:

```
function myFun2<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

But this is not nice, since there is no mention of the `SomeFunction` interface even though we basically match it.

Is there a better way to declare `myFun2` so we make sure it conforms to `SomeFunction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the interface like this

```js
interface SomeFunction {
    <T>(arg: T) : T
}
```

which then lets you write your function exactly as you want to

```js
const myFun: SomeFunction = arg => arg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It does indeed answer my question but now I have a follow up. What if I want to be able to constrain the generic type in my function declaration. I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001910/how-do-you-constrain-a-generic-type-in-a-typescript-function-interface