# How do you constrain a Generic type in a Typescript Function Interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's consider we have the following interfaces:

```js
interface SomeInterface {a: string; b: number}
interface SomeFunction<T> {(arg: T) :T}
```

We can use the function interface like so:

```js
const myFun: SomeFunction<string> = arg => arg;
```

but the issue with that is we specify the generic type `T` as string, so it is no longer generic.
I would like to keep the type `T` generic but also constrain it.

Declaring `SomeFunction` like:

```js
interface SomeFunction {<T>(arg: T) : T}
```

allows it to be used generically like:

```js
const myFun: SomeFunction = (arg) => arg;
```

but then we lose the chance to constrain `T` at the function declaration.

I would like my function that implements `SomeFunction` to define that `T` must extend `SomeInterface` and I would like another function that also implements `SomeFunction` to define that `T` extends something else.

So, basically, I want something like this:

```js
function myFun2<T extends SomeInterface>(arg: T): T {
    console.log(arg.a);
    return arg;
}

function myFun3<T extends {c: string }>(arg: T): T {
    console.log(arg.c);
    return arg;
}
```

The issue I have with the solution above is that there is no mention of the `SomeFunction` interface in these declarations even though we basically match it.

Is there a better way to declare `myFun2` and `myFun3`so we make sure they conform to `SomeFunction`?

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66999716/how-do-you-use-a-typescript-function-interface-with-a-generic-type#answer-67000230 ?

Comment: So, in that answer, you constrain `SomeFunction` in a way that you cant have 2 different functions with different constraints. I'll update this question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the ability to define constraints at call site, you can generalise  `SomeFunction` with a constraint type, like

```js
interface SomeFunction<C> {
    <T extends C>(arg: T) : T
}
```

and provide the correct constraint when defining your functions

```js
const myFun2: SomeFunction<SomeInterface> = arg => {
    console.log(arg.a) // ok
    return arg
}

const myFun3: SomeFunction<{ c: string }> = arg => {
    console.log(arg.c) // ok
    return arg
}
```

You could also give a default constraint of type `unknown` if you wanted to allow unconstrained functions, like

```js
interface SomeFunction<C = unknown> {
    <T extends C>(arg: T): T
}

const unconstrained: SomeFunction = arg => arg
```